# a query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with this field in sql server :
user_id , seller_id , cat_id , brand_id , action_type

action_type values is 0 , 1 , 2 , 3

I want a query that can show me per "user_id and seller id "

> the number of 0 fileds from action type
>
> the number of 1 fileds from action type
>
> the number of 2 fileds from action type
>
> the number of 3 fileds from action type

fo example :

> user1 seller1 cat1 brand1 0
>
> user1 seller1 cat1 brand1 0
>
> user1 seller1 cat2 brand1 1
>
> user1 seller1 cat2 brand1 0
>
> user1 seller1 cat1 brand1 0
>
> user1 seller1 cat3 brand1 2
>
> user1 seller1 cat3 brand1 2
>
> user1 seller1 cat4 brand1 2

i want a table in output that can show me the number of action type:
the column of output table is :

> user_id seller_id , seller action_type_0 , action_type_1
>   ,action_type_2 action_type_3

output:

> user1 seller1 4 1 3

description"

> 4:number of 0 in action_type per seller_id and user_id
>
> 1:number of 1 in action_type per seller_id and user_id
>
> 2:number of 2 in action_type per seller_id and user_id

Comment: What you have tried upto now? show us your sql script then we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for, but as others have commented, it would be much easier if you posted what you have tried so far.

```
Select User_ID, Seller_ID
, count(case when action_type = 0 then action_type end) as Type0
, count(case when action_type = 1 then action_type end) as Type1
[...]
from Table
group by User_ID, Seller_ID
```

Comment: @mskhfigshmskhfigsh I'm glad it was helpful.  If you do not need more help on this question, please accept the answer.